# How can i get the network Cell ID while i am on CDMA connection?

Tags: android

I can get my network cell id using `GsmCellLocation` object. but when i am on CDMA, 3G, HSDPA, or UMTS.....I cant get the Cell ID. using the `GsmCellLocation.getCid()` with 3G connection retrieves something called LCID (Logical Channel ID) which is not the Cid. The code i used to get the Gsm Cell ID shown below:

```
private PhoneStateListener mPhoneLocationListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
    public void onCellLocationChanged(CellLocation location) {
                    TelephonyManager tm  = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);                      
           GsmCellLocation location2 = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
           cellId = location2.getCid();
    }
}
```

but when i change the line:

```
GsmCellLocation location2 = (GsmCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
```

to :

```
CdmaCellLocation location2 = (CdmaCellLocation) tm.getCellLocation();
```

even when i am forcing my device to connect only to CDMA, exception is thrown with `CastException` saying cannot cast `GsmCellLocation` to `CdmaCellLocation`.

So how can i get the 3g cell id info ?

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
CellLocation cl = tm.getCellLocation();
        GsmCellLocation gsmLoc;
        CdmaCellLocation cdmaLoc;
        try {
            gsmLoc = (GsmCellLocation) cl;
            System.out.println(gsmLoc.getCid());
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            cdmaLoc = (CdmaCellLocation) cl;
            System.out.println("Base station ID - "+ cdmaLoc.getBaseStationId());
        }
```

Comment: It is better that you use operator instanceof in java . if (cell instaceof GsmCellLocation) ...

Answer (score 0):

CDMA dosen't have Cell ID . Instead it has 3 identifier :

1. SID - System ID
2. NID - Network ID
3. BID - Basestation ID

For more information see this page from OpenCellID wiki :
http://wiki.opencellid.org/wiki/Public:CDMA